# Compositing creating a nice edge around masked layer

Tags: compositing-nodes

I've masked the foreground arm in the below image, i'm trying to get a nice edge. It's either too sharp with a minimal dialate/erode with around a minus 10 pixel feather when seen above light background layers, or it's like the below image with a sharp minus 25 feather so it leaves a black border because it's eating away at the alpha channel which has been created with the mask. Is there a node setup which will leave a nice, maybe even a slightly transparent edge so it blends better with background layers underneath?

[image]

Comment: I refined the edge with feathering in the end, close to zero, then blurred the whole arm slightly and it improved it a little. Guess I need to mask a bit towards the outside next time.